# How can I select record by column value?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a realy simple data in my config/model

```
Author
  name Text
```

and I want to select author by name and not by id
I tried this ( the information comes from a form) :

```
FormSuccess book -> do
    result <- runDB $ selectSource [ AuthorName ==. title book]
```

And book is a data

```
data FormBook = FormBook {
  isbn :: Text
  , author :: Text
  , title :: Text
  , description :: Maybe Text
}
```

But I got this error

```
Couldn't match type `[SelectOpt Author]' with `HandlerT App IO'
Expected type: YesodPersistBackend
             App
             (HandlerT App IO)
             (Data.Conduit.Internal.Source m0 (Entity Author))
Actual type: [SelectOpt Author]
           -> Data.Conduit.Internal.Source m0 (Entity Author)
In the return type of a call of `selectSource'
Probable cause: `selectSource' is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of `($)', namely
`selectSource [AuthorName ==. (author book)]'
 In a stmt of a 'do' block:
authorresult <- runDB $ selectSource [AuthorName ==. (author book)]
```

I tried th put before Author  PersistenceEntity and PersistenceField but they are not in scope.
I do not have any other idea, except raw query.

Comment: Does `name` on the `author` table have a unique index? If there's not a unique index, you could be looking up multiple authors for a given book. However, ignoring that, I think this would work: `maybeAuthor <- runDB $ selectFirst [AuthorName ==. "foo"] []`.

Comment: Honestly I have now an other problem :(, I am working on a simple online bookstore.

Comment: Happy to answer any more questions you have. I'll try and monitor StackOverflow for any new ones.